# microSD card in SPI mode timing

Tags: c, embedded, atmel

I'm writing and reading values on a SD card in SPI mode. The frequency for writing and reading blocks of 512 bytes is set to 10Mhz. For writing a block it takes about 5ms and timing between blocks is about 10 ms.

**Is any way to improve the speed of writing?**

```
void sd_card_write_block(uint16 blockNumber, uint8* buffer)
{
  uint16 blockLow = 0;
  uint16 blockHigh = 0;
  uint8 dummy = 0;
  uint8 result = 0;
  uint8 data_block_start_byte = 0;
  uint8 write_command[SD_CMD_SIZE] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  uint8 dummy_buffer[DUMMY_BUFFER_LENGTH] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
  uint8 i = 0;
  uint8 check_response[CHECK_RESPONSE_SIZE] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  uint8 check_response1[CHECK_RESPONSE_SIZE] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  uint8 r1 = 0;
  uint16 retry = 0;
  uint8 response1 = 0;

  dummy = 0xFF;
  //initialize the dummy buffer to keep MOSI pin High
  for(i = 0; i < DUMMY_BUFFER_LENGTH; i++)
  {
    dummy_buffer[i] = 0xFF;
  }

  //set CS pin low
  spi_select_slave( &spi_master_instance, &slave, true);

  //send three clock cycles with MOSI HIGH (Ncs)
  spi_write_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, dummy_buffer, NCS_LENGTH);

  //block size was set in sd_init
  blockLow = ((blockNumber & 0x003F) << 9);
  blockHigh = ((blockNumber & 0xFFC0) >> 7);

  //send SD CMD24(WRITE_SINGLE_BLOCK) to write the data to SD card
  write_command[0] = 0x58;

  //high block address bits, blockHigh HIGH and LOW
  write_command[1] = (blockHigh >> 0x08);

  write_command[2] = (blockHigh & 0xFF);
  //low block address bits, blockLow HIGH and LOW
  write_command[3] = (blockLow >> 0x08);
  write_command[4] = (blockLow & 0xFF);

  //checksum is no longer required but send 0xFF
  write_command[5] = 0xFF;

  spi_write_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, write_command, SD_CMD_SIZE);


  spi_transceive_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, dummy_buffer, check_response, CHECK_RESPONSE_SIZE);

  //send three clock cycles with MOSI High
  spi_write_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, dummy_buffer, DUMMY_BUFFER_LENGTH);

  //set bit 0 to 0 which indicates the beginning of the data block
  data_block_start_byte = DATA_BLOCK_START_TOKEN;
  spi_transceive_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, &data_block_start_byte, &result, SD_RESPONSE_SIZE);


  /*takes so long because its similar to transreceivea and it discards the rx*/
  spi_write_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, buffer, SD_BLOCK_LENGTH);


  //read the microSD card response
  spi_transceive_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, dummy_buffer, check_response1, CHECK_RESPONSE_SIZE);

  do
   {
     // write dummy byte
     spi_transceive_buffer_wait( &spi_master_instance, &dummy, &response1, SD_RESPONSE_SIZE);

     r1 = response1;
     // do retry counter
     retry++;
     if(retry > MAX_TIMEOUT)
     {
       spi_select_slave( &spi_master_instance, &slave, false);
       break;
     }
   }
   while(r1 == END_OF_BLOCK_RESPONSE);
  //set the CS High
  spi_select_slave( &spi_master_instance, &slave, false);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you use for that reading/writing. It is difficult to help you without it.

Comment: Unfortunately, SD-cards are notoriously slow at writing anyway, no matter what you do with the interface:(

Answer (score 1):

You can't, atleast not by much. The reason being that the SPI mode itself is the bottleneck. So, you can use a few tricks here and there to get that speed up, but you really won't be benifitting much from it. I'd advise you to use SDIO if you really need that much speed (It's not as complicated as you might think). If you're using an AVR, try the xmega lineup (Don't quote me on that, I'm not quite informed in the AVR, since I use ARMs), or switch to another lineup completely.

Comment: I'm actually using a SAM D21G ARM cortex M0+.  Any direction will be great since I spent a lot of effort making it writing and reading blocks in SPI mode.

Comment: @Shahe Ansar It is not necessary true if there is inefficiency in code OP written and it can be fixed.

Comment: @MoldovanAlex As I stated, I'm not quite informed about Atmel products. But if it's a M0+, it should be able to do SDIO. Simply use that.

Comment: @return84 Yes, but really there isn't *much* headroom for improvement, atleast not with the timings he stated

Comment: Let's see: 512 bytes = 4kBit ==> at 10MHz, data transfer for a block of 512 bytes via SPI should take about 400µs; I doubt you can call SPI the bottleneck here, where 90% of the time is spent doing other things.

Comment: On the other hand, with 20MHz CPU clock you'd only have 16 clock cycles for each byte. Without DMA, this may become a bottleneck since 16 cycles is pretty tough to achieve without manual optimization and probably assembler language.

Comment: @You'd need assembly for both. While yes it IS possible to **kind of** improve the speed, he wouldn't get nearly as much performance. Also, SDIO is better if he wants speeds like that anyway. And just one thing, don't expect an SD card in SPI mode to work at 10Mbit/s (You're timings indicate that you think that's correct, but really, it's quite difficult to tell)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get high write speeds, you need to:
- use a faster clock
- use a wider bus
- Write larger blocks (2k or 4k) at a time

In other words, you pretty much need to use the SDIO spec.

There's also ways to begin a large sequential transaction and not end it until all the data has been received (but maybe that's in the SDIO spec and not the SPI command interface).  These sort of hints tells the controller that it can prepare a large section of the flash and not commit the write buffer until it's full.

And even then, you can end up with "very long" write cycles occasionally, so you cannot rely upon an SD card to stream high speed data off in real time without buffers on your side to handle the latency blips.

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted your `spi_write_buffer_wait` code but consider something like this:

Rearange the stuff in your actual write function where you send the data. Think about it. You have to wait until the SD Card indicates you, that the byte was written successfully. Use this "useless" wait time to prepare the next data.

```
/* write a single block */
for ( i = MMC_BLOCKLEN; i > 0; i-- ) {
    uint8_t data = *buffer;
    buffer++;
    wait_till_send_done();
    xmit_byte ( data );
}
wait_till_send_done();
```

There you prepare the byte to send and also move the pointer one byte forward **before** you start waiting for the SD Card to indicate its successfull writing of the previous byte.

It is also a good idea to check the generated ASM code...

If you are about to write more than 512bytes of data, consider using multiblock writes (4k blocks for example at once).

Usually SD cards have internal block sizes of more than 512bytes. So to write 512 bytes, they have to internally read for example 4k, exchange your 512bytes and write everything back... so to write more data at once is always a good idea...